# Arranging people around tables with empty seats

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> There are three cyclic tables in dinner room such that two of them have $3$ seats and the other has $4$ seats.All the seats in tables and two tables with three seats are identical.There are $8$ people to be seated to those tables. How many possible way exists ?

Solution:$$\frac{10!}{2\times2 \times3^2 \times 4}=25200$$

Explanation:

- $10!$ means the number of distinct people aligned in line.
- First two means two empty seats. In the beginning we assumed $10$ distinct people although there are $8$ people, so by dividing by $2$ we provided that assumption
- Second two is for making identical two tables with three seats
- $3^2$ is for arranging people in tables with three seats
- $4$ is for arranging people in table with four seats

**Question:** This method looks fine. However, it does not work some cases .For example, for $2$ people and $8$ empty seats, the method doesnt give correct answer. Can you explain the reason behind it ? In which situations doesnt this method work and why ?

$$\frac{10!}{8!\times2 \times3^2 \times 4}=1.25$$